# Further rvalue references and temporary objects

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

In elaboration of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586070/storing-rvalue-references-should-this-work) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583531/lvalue-to-rvalue-reference-binding), I'd like to understand what goes on in this real scenario. I have the following template function:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename HashFunction, typename Equals>
void FastHash<Key, Value, HashFunction, Equals>::Insert(const Key& key, const Value& value)
{
    Insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
}
```

called with, for instance, a mixture of lvalues and rvalues, like in this call:

```
std::string name = "The Great";
hashTable.Insert(name, "Gatsby");
```

(for testing purposes). `Insert` above calls

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename HashFunction, typename Equals>
void FastHash<Key, Value, HashFunction, Equals>::Insert(pair<const Key, Value>&& keyValuePair)
{
    if (buckets.size() == 0)
    {
        buckets.resize(1);
    }

    HashFunction hash;
    unsigned long hashValue = hash(keyValuePair.first) % buckets.size();
    buckets[hashValue].push_back(std::move(keyValuePair));
}
```

A few questions:

**1.** I would expect making a pair one of whose elements is a literal string to be undefined behaviour, owing to passing by reference. Is that so?

**2.** When I step into the `make_pair` line, the code first calls `make_pair(_Ty1&& _Val1, _Ty2&& _Val2)`, so it seems that the compiler is interpreting `key` and `value` as rvalues. Why?

**3.** The next call before going into the second `Insert` method is `pair(pair<_Other1, _Other2>&& _Right)`. This happens irrespective of whether the second `Insert` takes an `&&` or a `const &`. What's going on here?

**4.** Tied to this last, should the second `Insert` take a `const pair&` or a `pair&&`, given what it does?

**Update:** After watching Scott Meyer's excellent video on universal references, reading on template deduction and reference collapsing rules, and with your help I can answer 1, 2, and 4. But I still cannot understand why the `pair`'s move constructor is called just before the `Insert` call. Any help on that?

Comment: What is `hashTable`'s type?

Comment: A FastHash<string, string>. The hashing type and equality type are unimportant I guess.

Comment: A string literal has static storage duration.

Comment: `_Ty1&&` is a so-called *universal reference*. In this pattern `_Ty&&`, `_Ty1` can be deduced to be an lvalue reference (via a special rule, if the argument is an lvalue). If it is deduced to be an lvalue reference to `some_type`, reference collapsing applies and `some_type& &&` is collapsed to `some_type&` - the parameter becomes an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The next call before going into the second Insert method is `pair(pair<_Other1, _Other2>&& _Right)`. This happens irrespective of whether the second Insert takes an `&&` or a `const &`. What's going on here?

That is `std::pair`'s converting constructor: it's converting the pair that you pass - `std::make_pair(key, value)` - from `std::pair<Key, Value>` to the second `Insert` functions's parameter type `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. You could avoid the conversion if you specify the pair type yourself instead of having `std::make_pair` deduce it:

```
Insert(std::pair<const Key, Value>{key, value});
```

Of course, this is copying the parameters into a `pair`, and in C++11 we have the rule of thumb that if you are going to copy something you should accept it by value. So maybe implement this `Insert` as:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename HashFunction, typename Equals>
void FastHash<Key, Value, HashFunction, Equals>::Insert(Key key, Value value)
{
    Insert(std::pair<const Key, Value>{std::move(key), std::move(value)});
}
```

Comment: That was it! Nice answer. What I don't understand is this: "in C++11 we have the rule of thumb that if you are going to copy something you should accept it by value." Why? Where can I read more on this?

Comment: @KristianD'Amato In short, accepting by value makes a copy when the caller passes an lvalue and moves into the argument when the caller passes an rvalue. It's the best of both worlds. You should read Dave Abrahams [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)